# Use variable to match a node label in Neo4J CYPHER

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I will be running some complex MATCH which will return a node label to me. Then I want to trim the prefix of that node label and use the rest of it to further perform matches. I am trying to do this by assigning that rest of the part of the returned label to the variable and then using that variable to the label the node in `MATCH`.

However I feel this does not work since we cannot use a variable to label a node in `MATCH`.

For example create simple two node graph:

```
CREATE (:PrefixNodeLabel)
CREATE (:NodeLabel)
```

This:

```
MATCH(n:PrefixNodeLabel)
RETURN substring(labels(n)[0],6)
```

correctly returns `NodeLabel`.

I am trying to use this to label a node:

```
MATCH(n:PrefixNodeLabel)
WITH substring(labels(n)[0],6) AS nodeLabel
MATCH(m:nodeLabel)   //using a variable to label a node
RETURN m
```

But this does not return the `(:NodeLabel)` node.

I know what I am doing may look weird. But anyway how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot pass variable in place of Label

You can achieve this by

```
MATCH (n:PrefixNodeLabel)
WITH SUBSTRING(labels(n)[0],2) AS nodeLabel
MATCH (m)   
WHERE nodeLabel IN LABELS(m)
RETURN m
```

Comment: ahh I wish I could use variables with something extra syntax like `${variableName}` etc. That extra query is a bit pain.